# webview loading

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load the HTML content into an android Webview. I created a drop down where you can select any HTML content and that selected HTML content should load into the Webview below. But the data loading is not very consistent. The HTML is properly rendering in desktop browser. When a particular HTML content is selected Webview will display empty content and when tapped for 3-4 times data will load. When the HTML content is selected to load the previously selected content will also be present in the background. Any help would be much appreciated. Using the code mentioned below.

```
    WebView mWebViewContent = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebViewContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebViewContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mRelativeWebViewContent.getLayoutParams();
    mWebViewContent.clearHistory();
    mWebViewContent.clearFormData();
    mWebViewContent.clearCache(true);
    mWebViewContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, replaceHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
   // mWebViewContent.loadData(replaceHTML,"text/html","UTF-8");
    mRelativeWebViewContent.setLayoutParams(params);
    mRelativeWebViewContent.addView(mWebViewContent);
```

Currently I am creating Webview pro grammatically and adding it to a Relative Layout. When added use XML I also faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new webview and adding each time in relative layout.But are you removing it prior to adding if the relativelayout already contains the webview

Comment: Oh yea, thanks its working now.But when issue is there two HTML content upon loaded displaying empty and on tapping 3-4 times only the data is displayed. Any solution for that ?

Comment: It should not happen since the webview is newly created so loading the html content would display or refresh the webview.Issue could be might be that loading content is taking time.Could you add webview client and check that onPageFinished is called after loading.

Comment: Tried with WebView Client,No luck

Answer (score 0):

Add `WebView` only once in `RelativeLayout` in `onCreate` if is `activity` and when DropDpwn item is selected then just load that html content into webview.